Who is younger Kaikeyī or Sumitrā?
Throughout the Ayodhyā and other Kāṇḍas or the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇam , Sumitrā and Kaikeyī are mentioned as the middle mothers of Lord Rāma. somewhere Sumitrā is called the middle mother and somewhere Kaikeyī is called the Middle mother. Is there any interpolation in the Rāmāyaṇa because of which these confusions arise?
Please tell me who is the Middle mother of Lord Rāma? ,i.e who is younger? Please use references from Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa.
Thanks.
Jaya Śrī Rāma

This is a duplicate question i.e. it has been asked before - Who was Daśaratha’s second wife . If you have something, you wish to add, you may edit the linked question. And if you have an answer, you may give it there too, rather than here

Does this answer your question? Who was Dasharatha's second wife?

@Bingming Rāmāyaṇa 3.2.20 ( or 3.2.18 in the Critical Version) calls Kaikeyī "Madhyamā" and it is not said in the sense of "waist" but "Mātā mama Madhyamā" ? Why is that?

As per the commentaries Tattvadīpikā and Bhūṣaṇa, Kaikeyī is the youngest of the three mahiṣīs, but she is called 'madhyamā' in regards of being middlemost in age of the 350 other wives of Daśaratha. So, Kaikeyī is not madhyamā exactly among the mahiṣīs (i.e. the three chief queens).

also, I have given an answer, which you may check, if interested https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/59444/24460

@Bingming thanks! , I had some more questions, it would be great if you could answer them. 1st- Where was Queen Sumitrā from? Some say Kāśi although Kālidāsa in his Raghuvamśam tells us that she was from the Magadha Kingdom. 2nd- The capital of the Kekaya Kingdom is named Rājagṛha and Girivraja although in the critical addition -Girivraja occurs only once that too in the context of a city different from the Kekaya capital. My doubt is that - The capital of Magadha was also called Rājagṛha and Girivraja , is this a coincidence or is there any connection? Thanks!

you may ask separate questions on the site, maybe someone would be able to answer. Btw, where is it said that Sumitrā is from Kāśī?

@Bingming , Well the Raghuvamśam says that she was from Magadha and Wikipedia says that she's from Kāśī. Even people on quora say that she was a Kāśya princess. So I too want to know that on what basis they say that.

Raghuvaṁśa is a reliable source, quora and wikipedia aren't. You can't take quora, wikipedia, etc. as sources with validity like śāstras.

I would suggest you to post the question regarding Sumitrā's birthplace on this site. It's a good question. I will give an answer there, with some sources.

@Bingming , okk , I will. But can you please gather some sources regarding the Kekaya and Magadha thing. I'm really curious about how 2 cities - One in the Punjab region and the other in the Bihar region can have the same 2 names for there capital - Rājagṛha and Girivraja . I hope that you research on this for my sake. Thanks.

@Bingming , here's the question about Sumitrā - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/59459/where-was-sumitr%c4%81-from
